# What is this Canadian Half Dollar? Cannot find it anywhere

Tags: canada, money

I just found this half dollar in my house. perfect condition? is this worth anything?
[image]

[image]

Comment: How is this on topic?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about history.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace what is the generally accepted cut off from coins then. And if it is off-topic, should I delete my answer?

Comment: This question is about numismatics, not about history.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons The question isn't asking anything that isn't either easily googled and / or about history ('is it worth anything'). I've seen plenty of closed questions with undeleted answers so no need to delete your answer. In any case, the question hasn't even been put on hold / closed yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [a commemorative coin](https://en.numista.com/catalogue/pieces446.html) from the golden Jubilee of Queen Elizabeth the II
It's not worth much - the above link suggests £1.79 at the time of answer for circulated, which is presumably what you can get for it in the UK.